# How to install application in custom folder using wix installer,other than Program Files folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, wix

I have created an installer using wix. By default the application gets installed under Program Files folder.I need to create a folder for my application under `c:` directory and install my application inside there.

```
<Fragment>
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" >
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WIXDemoApp">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="c"/>
```

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
         <Component Id="MyApplication.exe">
     <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" Name="MyApp.exe" Id="MYAPPEXE" KeyPath="yes"  />
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
         </Component> 
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

I am getting the following error "`error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:INSTALLFOLDER' in section 'Fragment:'`".

**Update:**

```
<Fragment>
          <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WindowsVolume" >
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WIXDemoApp">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <SetDirectory Id="WindowsVolume" Value="c"/>
  </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">

            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
             <Component Id="MyApplication.exe">
         <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" Name="MyApp.exe" Id="MYAPPEXE" KeyPath="yes"  />
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
             </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

This is giving me another error `"error LGHT0204: ICE99: The directory name: WindowsVolume is the same as one of the MSI Public Properties and can cause unforeseen side effects.`".Googled and refereed [this](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Error-using-WindowsVolume-predefined-folder-td3313078.html)  and [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05670.html) to fix this.But not working for me,still i am getting the same error as "error LGHT0204: ICE99: The directory name: WindowsVolume is the same as one of the MSI Public Properties and can cause unforeseen side effects.".Any idea what would be the problem.

Comment: Are you planning an unattended installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Installer is case-sensitive so `WINDOWSVOLUME` won't work. You can do something like this:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="SetupProject1" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <SetDirectory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[WindowsVolume]SetupProject1" />
</Fragment>
```

For your second error, you're mixing two different ids: `INSTALLFOLDER` and `INSTALLLOCATION`. Pick one and use it in both places.

Comment: I have updated the question.I am getting this error "error LGHT0204: ICE99: The directory name: WindowsVolume is the same as one of the MSI Public Properties and can cause unforeseen side effects.".Please see my "update" in question.

Answer (score 5):

I found this tip on [kentie.net - Wix Tips & Tricks](http://kentie.net/article/wixtipstricks/). Tips said to use the *WINDOWSVOLUME* id.

> **TARGETDIR and the system partition**
>
> When trying to install to a subdirectory of the system drive root
>   (e.g. 'C:\application'), it might sense to assume that in something
>   like

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="SetupProject1">
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

> *TARGETDIR* refers to the system partition, as *ProgramFilesFolder* is
>   always given as a child of TARGETDIR. This is not the case; TARGETDIR
>   is the partition with the most free disk space. It can even be a
>   partition on an external hard drive. To set it to the true system
>   partition, use the below approach:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" >
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="SetupProject1">
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
 </Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]"/>
```

> The SetDirectory element
>   is required as trying to use WindowsVolume directly results in
>
> error LGHT0204: ICE99: The directory name: WindowsVolume is the same as one of the MSI Public Properties and can cause unforeseen side effects.
>   Signing MSIs

Comment: This approaching worked perfectly fine for me and it does not show the error LGHT0204: ICE99 error.

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful.